# What is correct definition of moment generating function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, moment-generating-functions

I had searched the literature and found two different definition of Moment Generating Function (MGF).

$$\phi_{w}(-s)=\int_0^{\infty}\text{exp}(-sw)f(w)\text{d}w \tag{1} $$

$$\phi_{w}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}\text{exp}(sw)f(w)\text{d}w \tag{2} $$

Out of these, which one is correct definition. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would say the **definition** of the moment generating function is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty m_k s^k/k!$ where $m_k$ is the $k$th moment, $k=0,1,2,\dots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both are wrong. The correct definition is the following

$$M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$$

when the expectation exists... not necessarily the expectation is an integral

for example, let $X\sim B(1;\theta)$, that is a bernoulli with parameter $\theta$, its MGF is given by

$$M_X(t)=e^0\cdot (1-\theta)+ e^t\cdot \theta=(1-\theta)+e^t\cdot \theta$$

Comment: Ok....can you please explain in more detail.

Comment: @Pranu added some details in my answer

Comment: I understood your opinion. If let us say expectation exists then which one is correct.

Comment: @Pranu: if the rv is defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ both of them are incorrect. If your rv is continuous and defined on $(0;+\infty)$ the two formulas are the same

Comment: @tommik....now I understood it completely....